# How to check if there is an element inside a two-dimensional array at a specific index location?

Tags: c, arrays

I am having this problem writing a function that when the user input x,y (the coordinate or index of two dimensional array) it will return 0 if there is nothing or 1 otherwise.

Comment: too difficult to understand..

Comment: There are always elements at every index location unless the index is outside the array.

Comment: I think he wants to know if certain index is inside or outside the array, something like IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions in Java but applied to C. I think you can't do that, you have to keep the track of your array size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do so, first thing you need to do is initializ the array. You can do it this way:

```
int i,j;
for (int i = 0; i<SizeX; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<SizeY; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Now you can easly check it this way:

```
int check (int arr[SizeX][SizeY] , int i , int j) {
    // out-of-bound check
    if (i < SizeX && j < SizeY) {
        return (arr[i][j] == NULL ? 0 : 1);
    }else {
        // -1 indicate error - out of bound indexes
        return (-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm being nitpicky here, I know, but I would probably remove the bounds check. Instead of performing it *every* time the function is called, you could place the onus on the caller to get it right.  As they are the ones passing in the bounds to begin with it seems fair. +1

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by nothing?

If you dont initialize your arry, it contains garbage values,

but if you do, u can check whether the cell contains the original value or a diffrent

one, and then return 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered the question on whether an element exists or not by checking for a sentinel value. These answers assume that the 2D array is already allocated. If your situation had a different mem allocation model (allocate 1D initially and allocate the 2D dynamically), then you would also have to check whether the 2D is actually allocated for any 1D index.
1D => first dimension; 2D => second dimension.